# multiple IAM user creation in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to create multiple users in terraform and attach them a policy.But its giving me error

Below is the code

```
provider "aws" {
  region     = "us-east-1"

  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::57XXXXXXX1:role/terraform-role"
  }
}
resource "aws_iam_user" "user" {
  for_each = var.module_enabled ? var.names : []

  name                 = each.key
  path                 = "/"

}
output "user" {
    value = "${aws_iam_user.user[*]}"
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "terraform-policy" {
  name        = "test_policy_terraform"
  path        = "/"
  description = "My test terraform policy"

  # Terraform's "jsonencode" function converts a
  # Terraform expression result to valid JSON syntax.
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = [
          "ec2:Describe*",
        ]
        Effect   = "Allow"
        Resource = "*"
      },
    ]
  })
}

output "policy-arn" {
   value = aws_iam_policy.terraform-policy.arn
}

resource "aws_iam_user_policy_attachment" "test-attach" {
/*  for_each = var.module_enabled ? var.names : []*/
  user       = "${aws_iam_user.user[*].name}"
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.terraform-policy.arn
}
```

terraform apply -var-file="mypars.tfvars" giving me below error.
name is one of attribute reference for resourc "aws_iam_user"

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type
  on user.tf line 46, in resource "aws_iam_user_policy_attachment" "test-attach":
  46:   user       = "${aws_iam_user.user[*].name}"
    |----------------
    | aws_iam_user.user is object with 3 attributes

Inappropriate value for attribute "user": string required.
Error: Unsupported attribute

  on user.tf line 46, in resource "aws_iam_user_policy_attachment" "test-attach":
  46:   user       = "${aws_iam_user.user[*].name}"
This object does not have an attribute named "name".
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `aws_iam_user_policy_attachment` you have to iterate over `aws_iam_user`. Thus what you commented out is correct

```
resource "aws_iam_user_policy_attachment" "test-attach" {

  for_each = var.module_enabled ? var.names : []

  user       = each.key
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.terraform-policy.arn
}
```

You could also use your `aws_iam_user` if you prefer:

```
resource "aws_iam_user_policy_attachment" "test-attach" {

  for_each = var.module_enabled ? aws_iam_user.user : {}

  user       = each.key
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.terraform-policy.arn
}
```